# BSplineSurface problem

Tags: splines

Why does the result of this function is straight line.If problem is in the order of my points, what order is correct?

```
l = {{{16.24, 44.3486, 642}, {16.24, 44.3652, 625}, {16.24, 44.3818, 
     717}, {16.24, 44.3984, 940}, {16.24, 44.415, 955}, {16.24, 
     44.4316, 798}, {16.24, 44.4482, 764}, {16.24, 44.4648, 
     671}, {16.24, 44.4814, 606}, {16.24, 44.498, 1125}, {16.24, 
     44.5146, 1315}, {16.24, 44.5312, 1265}, {16.24, 44.5478, 
     1083}, {16.24, 44.5644, 639}, {16.24, 44.581, 625}, {16.24, 
     44.5976, 640}, {16.24, 44.6142, 591},
    {16.24, 44.6308, 608},
    {16.24, 44.6474, 591},
    {16.24, 44.664, 596}},

   {{16.2566, 44.3486, 664},
    {16.2566, 44.3652, 820}, {16.2566, 44.3818, 1025}, {16.2566, 
     44.3984, 1020}, {16.2566, 44.415, 942}, {16.2566, 44.4316, 
     632}, {16.2566, 44.4482, 486}, {16.2566, 44.4648, 674}, {16.2566,
      44.4814, 1005}, {16.2566, 44.498, 1395}, {16.2566, 44.5146, 
     1643}, {16.2566, 44.5312, 1289}, {16.2566, 44.5478, 
     769}, {16.2566, 44.5644, 605}, {16.2566, 44.581, 653}, {16.2566, 
     44.5976, 620}, {16.2566, 44.6142, 627},
    {16.2566, 44.6308, 643},
    {16.2566, 44.6474, 635}, {16.2566, 44.664, 643}},

   {{16.2732, 44.3486, 848}, {16.2732, 44.3652, 1002}, {16.2732, 
     44.3818, 1023}, {16.2732, 44.3984, 969},
    {16.2732, 44.415, 905}, {16.2732, 44.4316, 573},
    {16.2732, 44.4482, 649}, {16.2732, 44.4648, 1092}, {16.2732, 
     44.4814, 1362}, {16.2732, 44.498, 1298}, {16.2732, 44.5146, 
     1219}, {16.2732, 44.5312, 968}, {16.2732, 44.5478, 
     720}, {16.2732, 44.5644, 599}, {16.2732, 44.581, 597}, {16.2732, 
     44.5976, 613}, {16.2732, 44.6142, 659},
    {16.2732, 44.6308, 669},
    {16.2732, 44.6474, 742}, {16.2732, 44.664, 824}},

   {{16.2898, 44.3486, 1120}, {16.2898, 44.3652, 1008}, {16.2898, 
     44.3818, 1014},
    {16.2898, 44.3984, 967}, {16.2898, 44.415, 758}, {16.2898, 
     44.4316, 447},
    {16.2898, 44.4482, 821}, {16.2898, 44.4648, 1289}, {16.2898, 
     44.4814, 1495}, {16.2898, 44.498, 1393}, {16.2898, 44.5146, 
     1247}, {16.2898, 44.5312, 955}, {16.2898, 44.5478, 
     668}, {16.2898, 44.5644, 616}, {16.2898, 44.581, 615}, {16.2898, 
     44.5976, 635}, {16.2898, 44.6142, 659},
    {16.2898, 44.6308, 753},
    {16.2898, 44.6474, 764}, {16.2898, 44.664, 891}},

   {{16.3064, 44.3486, 1062}, {16.3064, 44.3652, 889}, {16.3064, 
     44.3818, 771},
    {16.3064, 44.3984, 742}, {16.3064, 44.415, 492}, {16.3064, 
     44.4316, 684},
    {16.3064, 44.4482, 856}, {16.3064, 44.4648, 1326}, {16.3064, 
     44.4814, 1336}, {16.3064, 44.498, 1152}, {16.3064, 44.5146, 
     1206}, {16.3064, 44.5312, 772}, {16.3064, 44.5478, 
     681}, {16.3064, 44.5644, 622}, {16.3064, 44.581, 632}, {16.3064, 
     44.5976, 677}, {16.3064, 44.6142, 679},
    {16.3064, 44.6308, 852},
    {16.3064, 44.6474, 857}, {16.3064, 44.664, 879}}};

f = Graphics3D[{BSplineSurface[l, SplineDegree -> 3]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be the wide difference between the scale of the `z` axis and the scales of the `x` and `y` axes. Using the option `BoxRatios` with an explicit setting, say `1`,

```
Graphics3D[{BSplineSurface[l, SplineDegree -> 3]}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

gives

[image]